# How to Convert Method Based query to Query Expression in Linq

Tags: linq

I have following code and want to convert it to Query expression. (Exp. taken from msdn linq 101 sample)

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);


foreach (var d in shortDigits)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The word {0} is shorter than its value.", d);
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this, because query syntax does not support `Where` operator with index parameter. See remarks section at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx):

> In query expression syntax, a where (Visual C#) or Where (Visual
>   Basic) clause translates to an invocation of
>   `Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>`).

If you need index in query syntax, you can define it outside of query:

```
int index = 0;

var shortDigits = from d in digits
                  where d.Length < index++
                  select d;
```

Comment: @user3829651 what do you mean by calling Sum or Max using Where? Where  and Sum are different methods

Comment: it means there is no way.. Then why we call Both Query expression and Method based query equal

Comment: @user3829651 we don't call them equal. Query syntax is a small subset of Method syntax